# Caption on slider behaving incorrectly

Tags: jquery, css, html, slider

i have an issue with a caption I am adding to my slider where when scaling the page the height is inconsistent. It isn't sitting on the page in an absolute position. If I add the position absolute it vanishes?

Heres my code:

```
<div style="heigt: 500px;">
<div class="callbacks_container">
      <ul class="rslides" id="slider4">
       <li><img src="img/businessbig.jpg" alt="">

       <p class="caption">Welcome to Ashley Tate
            <br />
        Thank you for finding time to visit our website – whether you are looking to purchase or are considering selling your business then we are here to help.
            <br />
    Experience counts for everything in business sales and the principle people at Ashley Tate have each been personally involved in business sales and acquisitions for more than thirty years.
            <br />
        Our approach to business sales is refreshingly different; our objective is to deliver professional advice and guidance borne out of an understanding of the sales process and of the market place. </p>

       </li>

      <!--<li><img src="img/cateringbig.jpg" alt=""></li>
      <li><img src="img/nurseriesbig.jpg" alt=""></li>-->
    </ul>
</div>
 </div>
```

Heres the css:

```
.caption {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-shadow: none;
  color: #fff;
  background: #000;
  background: rgba(255,255,255, .8);
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin: 0;
  margin-top:- 400px;
  float: left;
 }
```

Its when they scale into my media queries it shows on the smaller screens but gets pushed down underneath the image on the larger screen sizes.

Comment: `<div style="heigt: 500px;">` height is missing an "H"

Comment: @CvR Nice spot - sorry about that I was altering the markup - this didnt affect it though?

Comment: Nope, just thought I make a note to you since it might mess up something else ^.^. Still working on the issue about the caption.

Answer (score 0):

It’s hard to tell without seeing the rest of your code but usually this happens when a parent element is not set to `position: relative`.

An absolutely positioned element must be relative to a parent. Try adding `position: relative` to the `li`

Comment: So here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/Qc3hu/ it do not want the caption to be sticky at the bottom of that window because that is what is happening on my site too. But for it to be in a position where I want it to be - I have tried floating it and other methods but with no joy.

Answer (score 0):

In your `@media` (media queries), add `.caption` and try to change `padding: 10px 20px;` or `margin-top: -400px;` (which has a type 'o too if you look closely). It might be that you have to re-position it in your media queries, but that the re-positioning is variable to what screensize it goes to.

The other possibility is (as @Stuart says), other elements around use another form of `position:` which messes up the positioning of your `.caption` element.

Good luck!

Comment: I have tried both the above and with no success - It is a strange one indeed. I will try and mimic my code in a fiddle.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Qc3hu/ here is the example - the problem being that I dont want it to be sticky to the bottom of the window but almost floating so I can change the position on each slide or atleast have this floating

Comment: You might be able to solve it by adding `min-height:` to each media query? It's hard to check responsiveness using Fiddle though.

Comment: I also feel like `margin: 0;` and `margin-top: -400px` are overruling each other.

Comment: The fiddle is behaving exactly as my site is - I have taken off the float and absolutely positioned it - the problem being now that as the image that it sits on top of gets bigger when the screen scales the caption is stuck to it and vanishes behind the content below...

Comment: Ah, and you have tried different "position" properties? http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp Cus that might be because it is stuck, because it has been set on hard coördinates `left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0`

Comment: I have this now: `.caption {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-shadow: none;
  color: #000;
  background: #000;
  background: rgba(255,255,255, .8);
  padding: 10px 20px;
  float: left;
  margin: -600px 0 0 0;
 }`

Comment: I have fixed the problem - I literally removed all margins altogether and put the absolute position back in and only applied it to the main style and wrapped it in my wrapper div and its scaling down as it should be (Odd I know).